# Cancel submitting if required fields are not filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I`ve got a regiester form on my website. I am using jQuery to check if required fields are filled.  Since now I have two must be fields - two text inputs

Here is the form

```
<form id="regiesterForm" method="post">
    <div id="regPseudoDiv">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pseudo, new { @id = "txtPseudo", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Pseudonim", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" })
    </div>
    <div id="regPhoneDiv">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Numer telefonu", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" })
    </div>
    <div id="regEmailDiv">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @type = "email", @id = "txtEmail", @onchange = "checkEmail()", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" })
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Born, new { @type = "datetime", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Data urodzenia" })

    <div class="radio-inline">
        <label style="font-size:10px">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female")Kobieta</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
        <label style="font-size:10px">@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male") Mezczyzna</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text-right">
        <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit" id="regiesterButton" class="btn btn-success" value="Zarejestruj" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here`s the jQuery code:

```
$('#regiesterForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    if ($('#txtPseudo').val() == 'undefined' || $('#txtPseudo').val() == null) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#regPseudoDiv').addClass('form-group has-warning');
    }
    if ($('#txtEmail').val() == '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#regEmailDiv').addClass('form-group has-error');
    }
 })
```

The point is after this function there is an error in bootstrap.min.js
After debugging all seem to be ok but there is an error.

The error:

```
if(!jQuery)throw new Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery");+function(a){"use strict";function b(){var a=document.createElement("bootstrap"),b={WebkitTransition:"webkitTransitionEnd",MozTransition:"transitionend",OTransition:"oTransitionEnd otransitionend",transition:"transitionend"};for(var c in b)if(void 0!==a.style[c])return{end:b[c]}}a.fn.emulateTransitionEnd=function(b).......................... LONG
```

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery.js is included and that is included before bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Bootstrap+requires+jQuery

Comment: I have others functions which are working

Comment: You could always alter the button from a submit to a function button,
Run the validation code and then submit the form manually